Find all homogeneous distribution $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^1)$ with degree of $0$ or $1$

Homogeneous Distribution means a distribution $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfying $\langle \lambda^{-d}u,\varphi\rangle=\langle u,\lambda^n\varphi(\lambda x)\rangle$ for every $\lambda>0$. And $d$ is its degree.

We can the equivalent definition of $\langle u,\varphi\rangle=\lambda^{d+n}\langle u,\varphi(\lambda x)\rangle$ to check it.
Many common distributions are homogeneous. For example, $\text{p.v.}\frac1x,x_+^\alpha\;(\alpha>-1),\delta_0$ are all homogeneous for $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^1)$. Their degrees are $-1,\alpha,-1$ respectively.
For details, we can know $x_+^\alpha$ is a homogeneous distribution with degree of $\alpha$ by:
$$\lambda^{\alpha+1}\langle x_+^\alpha,\varphi(\lambda x)\rangle=\int_0^\infty \lambda^{1+\alpha}x^\alpha \varphi(\lambda x)dx=\int_0^\infty \lambda^\alpha x^\alpha\varphi(\lambda x)d\lambda x\overset{t=\lambda x}{==}\int_0^\infty t^\alpha\varphi(t)dt=\langle x_+^\alpha,\varphi\rangle$$
And we know:

If $u$ is a homogeneous distribution with degree of $d$, then $\partial_{x_1}u$ is also a homogeneous distribution with degree of $d-1$.


Proof
First, we have $\displaystyle \left\langle \lambda^{-d}u,\varphi \right\rangle = \left\langle u,\lambda^{n} \varphi(\lambda x) \right\rangle $. So $$\displaystyle \left\langle \lambda^{-d+1}\partial_{x_{1}}u,\varphi \right\rangle=\left\langle \lambda^{-d+1}u,-\partial_{x_{1}}\varphi \right\rangle=\left\langle \lambda u, -\lambda^{n}(\partial_{x_{1}}\varphi)(\lambda x)\right\rangle=\left\langle u,-\lambda^{n}\partial_{x_{1}}(\varphi(\lambda x)) \right\rangle=\left\langle \partial_{x_{1}}u,\varphi(\lambda x) \right\rangle $$Then we know its degree is $\displaystyle d-1 $.

The problem is to find all homogeneous distribution in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^1)$ with degree of $0$ or $1$. Obviously, we can choose $px+q$. But how to find other homogeneous distribution which satisfies the condition, especially for the non-regular distribution?

How about $u(x)=xH(x),$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function? Is that homogeneous?

@md2perpe, yes, we can regard it as $x_+$. And we have $\langle x_+,\varphi\rangle=\lambda^2\langle x_+,\varphi(\lambda x)\rangle$. So it's homogeneous and its degree is 1.

For details, $\langle x_+,\varphi\rangle=\int_0^\infty x\varphi(x)dx\overset{x=\lambda t}{===}\int_0^\infty \lambda t\varphi(\lambda t)d\lambda t=\lambda^2\int_0^\infty t\varphi(\lambda t)dt=\lambda^2\langle x_+,\varphi(\lambda x)\rangle$.

@md2perpe, I have updated some details.

I know. Unfortunately I don't have a solution.

@md2perpe, I've finished it. Take a look at the answer below.

We need two lemmas.

(Euler’s Formula for Homogeneous Distributions) Given $ u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n) $, $ d \in \mathbb{R} $. Then $ u $ is a homogeneous distribution of degree $ d $ if and only if
$$
    \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_k} = d \cdot u.
$$


Proof: Consider that $\displaystyle u $ being homogeneous distribution with degree of $\displaystyle d $ is equivalent to $\displaystyle \lambda^{-(n+d)}\left\langle u,\varphi \right\rangle=\left\langle u,\varphi(\lambda x) \right\rangle $. Then we take the derivative of $\displaystyle \lambda $, we will get $\displaystyle -(n+d)\lambda^{-(n+d+1)}\left\langle u,\varphi \right\rangle=\left\langle u,\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cdot\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_{k}}(\lambda x) \right\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\langle x_{k}u,\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x_{k}}(\lambda x) \right\rangle=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\langle \frac{\partial (x_{k}u)}{\partial x_{k}},\varphi(\lambda x) \right\rangle =-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\langle u+x_{k}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}},\varphi(\lambda x) \right\rangle=-n\left\langle u,\varphi(\lambda x) \right\rangle-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\langle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}},\varphi(\lambda x) \right\rangle  $. Now let $\displaystyle \lambda=1 $, so we get $\displaystyle \left\langle d\cdot u-\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}},\varphi \right\rangle=0 $ for any $\displaystyle \varphi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) $. Thus $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}=d\cdot u $.


Distribution $v\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^n)$. If $v'=0$, then $v=c$.


Proof: First, we have $0=\langle v',\varphi\rangle=-\langle v,\varphi'\rangle$. Notice that, $\displaystyle \left\langle v,\varphi' \right\rangle=0 $ for all $\displaystyle \varphi\in \mathcal{D}  $ means $\displaystyle \left\langle v,\phi \right\rangle=0 $ for all $\displaystyle \phi\in \mathcal{D} $ satisfying $\displaystyle \int\phi=0 $. So it's equivalent to $xu=k$. Then we fix $\displaystyle \psi_{0}\in \mathcal{D} $ with $\displaystyle \int\psi_{0}=1 $. Let $\psi\in \mathcal{D},\displaystyle \alpha=\int \psi,c=\left\langle v,\psi_{0} \right\rangle $, now $\displaystyle \int\alpha\psi_{0}-\psi=0 $. So $\displaystyle \left\langle v,\alpha\psi_{0}-\psi \right\rangle=0 $, that is, $\displaystyle \left\langle v,\psi \right\rangle=\left\langle v,\alpha\psi_{0} \right\rangle=c\int\psi $.


For the distribution with degree of $\displaystyle 0 $, we have $\displaystyle x\cdot u'=0 $ by Euler's Formula. And we know $\displaystyle u'=c\delta_{0} $. That's because the support set of $u'$ is only $\{0\}$, so we can get it by undetermined coefficient method. And because of $\displaystyle H'(x)=\delta_{0} $, it has a particular solution $\displaystyle u=cH(x) $. Then consider the general solution for $\displaystyle u'=0 $, which is $\displaystyle u=k $. So the solutions are $\displaystyle u=cH(x)+k $.

For the distribution with degree of $\displaystyle 1 $, we have $\displaystyle x\cdot u'=u $ by Euler’s Formula. Then we know $\displaystyle x\cdot u''=0 $. So we know $\displaystyle u'=cH(x)+k $ by the degree of $0$. And we know $\displaystyle u=0 $ when $x=0$. Thus we know $\displaystyle u=\begin{cases}ax,x>0\\bx,x<0\end{cases} $.

Be careful when you solve $xu'=u$. You are not allowed to multiply $u$ with $\frac1x.$

The solutions to $xu'=u$ are $$u=\begin{cases}ax&(x<0)\bx&(x>0)\end{cases}$$

@md2perpe, Thanks, but how can I find the solutions for $xu'=u$ if not multiply by $\frac1x$?

Take the derivative of both sides of $xu'=u$ and you will find something interesting.

@md2perpe, oh, Isee! Thank you!
